# Using WPF/C# to get information about the processor

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to get basic information about the computer's processor in a WPF application I'm writing.

Data such as "Intel(R) core(TM) 2 Quad CPU Q6600 @ 2.4GHz"

How do I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get the processor NAME of my machine using C#(.NET 3.5)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708663/how-can-i-get-the-processor-name-of-my-machine-using-c-net-3-5)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use WMI

```
using System.Management;

private static string GetProcessorID()
    {

      ManagementClass mgt = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
      ManagementObjectCollection procs= mgt.GetInstances();
        foreach ( ManagementObject item in procs)
             return item.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString();

        return "Unknown";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This information (and much, much more) is available via [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302051.aspx) (or WMI for short). It isn't technically tied to WPF. Please take a look at [this article](http://ondotnet.com/pub/a/dotnet/2003/04/07/wmi.html) to get you started!

Answer (score 0):

Some of what you're looking for is exposed by properties of the `System.Environment` class.  You might also be interested in the `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use WMI to obtain the information needed, especially the classes in the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace. First. add a reference to the System.Management assembly, then use code similar to this one:

```
ManagementClass wmiManagementProcessorClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Processor");
ManagementObjectCollection wmiProcessorCollection = wmiManagementProcessorClass.GetInstances();
foreach (ManagementObject wmiProcessorObject in wmiProcessorCollection)
{
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(wmiProcessorObject.Properties["Name"].Value.ToString());
    }
    catch (ManagementException ex)
    {
        // real error handling here
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```