# c# Cant get ManagmentObjectSearcher from System.Managment

Tags: c#

Im trying to get hardware info from PC using `ManagmentObjectSearcher` (CPU, GPU etc).

Its pretty clear, that this class is included in `System.Management` (like is said in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.management.managementobjectsearcher(v=vs.110).aspx) Site).

Could you tell me, how to get this object? I give a reference to this `using` statement.

The error that i get is:

> CS0246  C# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

If it will help, my code:

```
using System.Management; //no error here

 namespace KMM_HighPerformance.Models
{
    class GetHardwareInfo
    {

        static public void GetCPU()
        {
            ManagmentObjectSearcher m = new ManagmentObjectSearcher(); //i get red line here
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for any advices!

Comment: You're trying to call a class like a method. Did you mean `ManagmentObjectSearcher m = new ManagmentObjectSearcher();`?

Comment: Yes, i tried to do this but its still red-lined

Comment: I Edited my question, now it will be more clear i think

Comment: BTW, there is a typo: ManagmentObjectSearcher should be ManagementObjectSearcher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change typo "ManagmentObjectSearcher" to "`ManagementObjectSearcher`" .

Try this if you want get processor ID:

```
using System.Management; 

 namespace KMM_HighPerformance.Models
 {
    class GetHardwareInfo
    {

        static public void GetCPU()
        {
            var mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select ProcessorID From Win32_processor");
            var mbsList = mbs.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)
            {
               var cpuid = mo["ProcessorID"].ToString();

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you know, how to get Processor Name property?

Comment: @metadon789 See this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708663/how-can-i-get-the-processor-name-of-my-machine-using-c-net-3-5?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 3):

Under the project name right click on references - > Add reference
in the newly opened windows under assemblies search for `System.Management`
just tick System.Management one and press okay

[image]

Comment: I wrote in my question, that i added reference in `References` and its still not work

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to the DLL `System.Management`. your code should work.

and also change `ManagmentObjectSearcher` to `ManagementObjectSearcher`

Comment: I wrote in my question, that i added reference in References and its still not work

Comment: Did you fix the typo ?